# como clicar no botão "ok" em um alerta do Internet Explorer usando o VBA?

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, popup, excel-vba, alert

Olá, tenho um codigo em VBA que acessa uma pagina web e exclui os itens cadastrados.

No momento que eu clico no botão **"excluir item"** abre um alerta na tela com dois botões (**"ok"** e **"cancel"**) e exibindo a mensagem **"confirmar a exclusão do local de entrega?"**

Eu queria saber como eu faço para clicar no botão **"ok"**.

Segue trecho do codigo:

```
    For Each elements In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input")
        If elements.name = "quantidadeTotalInformada" Then
            quantidaeTotal = elements.Value
        End If
    Next

    If quantidaeTotal > 0 Then
        For Each element In IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If element.innertext = "Selecione" Then
                element.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
'o popup aparece depois de clicar neste botão
        IE.Document.getElementById("id_btnExcluirLocal").Click 
    End If
```

Comment: não manjo vba mas andei vendo por ai  IE.Document.forms(0).submit e algo assim IE.Document.getelementsbyname("subAction")(0).Click

Comment: eu encontrei uma forma utilizando o **FindWindow()** para achar o popup e o **SendKeys()** para enviar o comando de click no botão **"ok"**.

Comment: porem tem um problema, depois de eu clicar no botão  de excluir **(IE.Document.getElementById("id_btnExcluirLocal").Click)**, o popup aparece e o código trava e so continua se eu clicar (com o mouse), em **"ok"** ou **"cancela"**

Comment: após esperar alguns minutos o excel mostra a mensagem "o microsoft excel esta aguardando que outro aplicativo conclua a ação OLE "

Comment: Tenta dar um SendKeys pra ver se resolve

Comment: o SendKeys até acha o alerta que o ie abre... porem se a macro disparar o botão "id_btnExcluirLocal" o ie trava a execução do código e só libera se eu, manualmente, clicar em ok ou fechar o alerta